# Python crashes when opening Spyder with python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Python 3.5 environment is installed on anaconda in Win10 system. When I try to launch Spyder, python.exe crashes. On the terminal, it shows

```
[4596:5756:0409/160956.599:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has ended (0x6D)
[7064:1908:0409/160956.599:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has ended (0x6D)
```

However, when I change to the Python 3.6 environment, Spyder works normally. Does anyone has some ideas to fix the "**broken pipe**" issue?

---

The whole story is like that.
I want to install PIL package on Python 3.5 environment previously. Unfortunately, I use the wrong command "conda install PIL". As a result, python 2.7 is introduced in 3.5 environment. I guess the broken pipe comes from this operation.

Then I tried to uninstall Spyder, python 3.5 and anaconda, but nothing works.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments when you are trying all this?

Comment: Thanks， I’m using the real environment. Finally, I installed the tensorflow in Python 3.6, not Python 3.5 any more.

Answer (score 2):

Just reset preferences with:

```
spyder --reset
```

and then run `spyder` again.

It should work.